# Can Razor Page asp-for calls use dynamic variables as part of the asp-for value

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I was wondering if there is a way i can take string values from a class i have and then use those string values as inserts into the values of asp-for on a Razor Page? My example will help explain what i'm trying to do and if it's even possible.

I have a class like below that just contains the names of the Days of the Week... Then I want to be able to dynamically use the Names of the week to build out asp-for values that are actual var/property names.. Like in asp-for="@(Day)StartTime"  , it would actually be a var in code behind named SaturdayStartTime, SundayStartTime, etc...  then for @SpanHours the same would apply there is a property off MyObject which is MyObject.SaturdaySpanHours , MyObject.SundaySpanHours , etc...  so basically was just hoping to be able to foreach as i've done below but of course that doesn't work. Is there another method to be able to dynamically insert values into the asp-for's ?? thanks

```
public class Days
{
    [BindProperty]
    public static List<string> DaysList { get; set; } = new List<string>
    {
        new string("Saturday"),
        new string("Sunday"),
        new string("Monday"),
        new string("Tuesday"),
        new string("Wednesday"),
        new string("Thursday"),
        new string("Friday")
    };

}  

  <div>
        @{ 
            foreach (string Day in Days.DaysList)
            {
                string SpanHours = "MyObject." + Day + "SpanHours";
            
                <input type="time" value="@Model.MyObject.@(Day)StartTime.ToString("HH:mm")" asp-for="@(Day)StartTime" />
                <input asp-for="@SpanHours" class="form-control" value=@Model.MyObject.@(Day)SpanHours />
            
            }
        }

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't use `asp-for`! instead use `name` and `id`:

```html
<input name="@SpanHours" id="@SpanHours" class="form-control" value=@Model.MyObject.@(Day)SpanHours />
```